# Trying to psping to azure machine firewall is off, but still unable to connect

Tags: azure

I have an azure pc in Windows server 2008 r2.  The fire wall is off.  I have defined html, opened port 80 and evneport8080.  I have defined a end point too
but when I do psping  ipaddress:80 the remote computer refused the network connection.  But if I try to psping ipaddress:3389 it seems to work, but not any new port I have created.

What is this msg, and will it impact my connectivity?

[image]

Comment: seems port 80 is not open but if you see the image but command netstat findstr  shows that port 908 is open please seee the enter image description you shall understand what i mean, Kindly help Thanks

Comment: Please run this command on Azure VM, `netstat -ant`, can you find port 80 and 8080 in the result? another test, can you browse your web in Azure VM?

Comment: no i dotn find port 80 or 8080  though net is working on the vmwar emachine ..

Comment: Your web application running on Azure VM or vmware?

Comment: Yes you took me in right direction .Thanks the issue is solved i checked it now ..The webserver itself was not running ..so i will the  trick you mentioned help me find the issue ie netstat -ant .. i found no  ports were listneing ..and then i understood i had to run jasper etc thanks for your time and cheers

Comment: It seems your VM create in classic module, please add endpoints to this VM. Please refer to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/setup-endpoints

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an NSG rule to allow TCP traffic on port 80.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal

By default, an NSG rule is added to allow only port 3389.

[image: Add NSG rule for port 80]

Comment: Let me check it i was angry  cause i had used other cloud providers they didnt have this issue .. it results in waste of time of people ..users i mean but luckily you came in right timing let me check it ..Thanks

Comment: Stilll the same issue tried it .. seems the port 80 is not open..dont know strange issue ..

Comment: I had missed the ending subnet part so trying those thanks

Comment: Thanks for the tip issue got sorted.   Those manuals you mentioned where helpfull thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, we should check your web service is running or not, we can use `netstat -ant` to check it.

---

Update:
Does your VM create in Azure **classic** module?

if yes, we should add **endpoints** to your Azure VM via azure portal, like this:
[image]

More information about add endpoints, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/setup-endpoints).

Also we can add endpoints in Azure classic portal:

[image]